# Wasserstein attains its infimum

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, concentration-of-measure, optimal-transport

let $(\mathcal{X},d)$ be a Polish space. For $p\geq1$ let $\mathcal{P}_p(\mathcal{X})$ be the space of all Borel probability measures $\mu$ on $\mathcal{X}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_\mu\left[ d^p(X,x_0) \right]<\infty
\end{equation}

On this space we can define the Wasserstien distance (turns out to be a metric) as

\begin{equation}
W_{p}(\mu,\nu) =  \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)}\left(\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}}d^p(x,y) \pi(dx,dy) \right)^{1/p} 
\end{equation}

where $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is the set of all probability measures on the space $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X}$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Raginsky Sason 2014 Concentration of Measure Inequalities in Information Theory, Communications and coding, page 109, states that the inf is actually attained and therefore is a minimum. Does anyone know a proof for this? or point me in the direction of one? I cant seem to find it.

Comment: Theorem 8.10.45 in Bogachev, _Measure Theory_, vol. 2

Answer (score 2):

One possible reference has been given in the comments, another one is Theorem 4.1 in Villani, *Optimal transport, old and new*. However, the argument is simple enough to reproduce it here.

First note that the set $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is tight and weakly closed, hence weakly compact by Prokhorov's theorem. Moreover, since $d^p$ is the supremum of bounded continuous functions, the functional
$$
I\colon \Pi(\mu,\nu)\to[0,\infty],\,I(\pi)=\int d(x,y)^p\,d\pi(x,y)
$$
is weakly lower semicontinuous. Thus $I$ attains its minimum.

(More explicitly, take a minimizing sequence $(\mu_n)$. Since $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is weakly compact and metrizable, we can extract a weakly convergent subsequence $(\mu_{n_k})$ with limit $\mu$ in $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$. Since $I$ is weakly lower semicontinuous, we have
$$
I(\mu)\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}I(\mu_{n_k}).
$$
Thus $\mu$ is a minimizer.)

Comment: Good answer, thanks for the reference. Therefore I have given an up vote. I am going to also submit a slightly more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

First we will need two lemmas from Villani Optimal Transport, old and new. Lemma 4.3, from  says that the functional $F :\pi \to \int d^{p} \pi $ is lower semi continuous on the space $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X})$ with respect to the weak topology. Lemma 4.4, states that if we have two tight subsets $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ of 
    $\mathcal{P}_p(\mathcal{X})$ then the set $\Pi(\mathcal{M}_1,\mathcal{M}_2)$ is tight in $\mathcal{P}_p(\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X})$.

Now, since $\{\mu \}$ is clearly convergent to $\mu$, and $\mathcal{X}$ is Polish we have that $\mu$ is tight. Similarly $\nu$ is tight. So $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is tight in $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X})$, and we can apply Prokhorov's Theorem $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is precompact (its closure is compact). Furthermore $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is weakly closed (which we will show at the end)  hence it is in fact compact.

Let $\pi_{k}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ such that $\int d^p \pi_k$ converges to \newline
    $ \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int d^p(x,y) \pi(dx,dy)   $ . Now using that $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is closed and compact we can say that $\pi_k \to \pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu) $ ( extracting a sub-sequence and relabeling if necessary ). We have yet to show that $\pi$ is minimizer.

Now using that $F$ is lower semi-continuous :

\begin{align*}
  F(\pi) \leq & \liminf_{\pi_k \to \pi} F(\pi_k)  \\
  \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}} d^p(x,y) \pi(dx,dy) \leq & \liminf_{\pi_k \to \pi} \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}}  d^p(x,y) \pi_k (dx,dy) \\
  = & \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}}  d^p(x,y) \pi_k (dx,dy)
  \end{align*}

So $\pi$ is such a minimiser, and by the reasoning above one can see that $\pi$ is indeed in the set $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$. Hence the infimum exists and is in fact an minimum.

As promised, $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is weakly closed since : if $\pi_k ~ \underset{weakly}{\to} ~\pi$ then for all bounded continuous functions $f$

$$ \int f d\pi_k \to \int f d\pi  $$ in particular

$$ \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} } f(x) \pi_k(dx,dy) \to \int_{\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}} f(x) \pi(dx,dy)  $$
that is, since $\pi_k$ has marginal $\mu$ and we choose $f$ to only depend on one variable :

$$\int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \mu(x) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \pi(dx,\mathcal{X})  $$

for all bounded continuous $f:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$, from which it can be shown $\pi(\cdot,\mathcal{X})=\mu$. Hence $\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)$. Which completes the proof.